# drupal 7 site is too slow

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I just started practicing drupal 7 on my computer but it is terribly slow.

Whenever I try to enable an extension module, the process times-out, meaning that it exceeds the 30-second limit. So I try again(and again on further time-outs) until successfully enabled. But the module download and installation works  fine at good speed and this is in fact the only operation on my drupal 7 without any speed problems.

When I click on a link to any page, it takes about 20-seconds(at best) to open such page, sometimes beyond 30-seconds. I don't think this is normal. I have made two drupal test sites on my computer with the same behaviours. I tried with all browsers(IE, chrome, opera, firefox & safari) with no improvement. I use a windows vista on my computer.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I just fixed the time-out issue. Can somebody tell me what the normal average time to open a link on drupal 7 is?

Comment: The problem could be windows vista.

Comment: Joke aside, this question is completely unanswerable. On my computer, Drupal is almost instant.

Answer (score 3):

Module installation operation needs normaly more than 30 seconds, You must add some seconds in your php.ini to the variable **max_execution_time** . 30 seconds is the default value, so you can change it to 120 (2minutes) or 180 (3minutes).
**max_execution_time = 180** would solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, that was great help. Do you have any idea why my links take so much time to open? Or what is the normal average time to open links?

Comment: Check your cache settings, when enabled, caching system improve slightly your site performances. You can access cache settings with this url : **http://mysite.com/admin/config/development/performance**

Answer (score 3):

try to increase php memory limit. Drupal 7 is not using exceptional amount of resources and should be ok to run on a mid-low end server. i suggest to use 128Mb of memory.

ref: http://drupal.org/requirements